# Unity3d with Xbox Live & Mixer Interactive Plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox-live

I'm using Unity3d 5.6.0f3 and develop a game which uses the [Xbox Live Creators Plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-unity-plugin) and the [Mixer-Interactive-Plugin](https://github.com/mixer/interactive-unity-plugin).

My problem is that both uses the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in different versions, so I got the error message:

> error CS1703: An assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' with the same identity has
>   already been imported. Consider removing one of the references
>   Assets/Xbox Live/Libs/Unity/Newtonsoft.Json.dll (Location of the
>   symbol related to previous error)
>   Assets/MixerInteractive/Source/DLLs/Win32/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
>
> Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Removing one of these assemblies gives an DirectoryNotFoundException in addition, but the previous mentioned error message still exists.

Is there any way to manage references or does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was too easy ...

Because the Mixer Interactive Plugin is open source and no pre-compiled assembly with static dependencies, it was possible to just untick all Newtonsoft.Json-references at the import process to unity.

Answer (score 1):

Thank for bringing this up. The quickest way to fix it is to delete Newtonsoft.Json.dll from one of the two plugins. Deleting it from the Xbox Live plugin is simpler (since the plugin has fewer platform checkboxes checked).

We'll see what we can do to make this better.